# Using IEEEtran provided template , i put my refereences in IEEEabrv.bib but they are not abreviating

Tags: bibliographies

[image]

Should i reformat thm into shortr titles manually ?

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SX! // Are you using the correct format? for example `journal = IEEE_J_IT` will be abbreviated as *IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory*. // Any reference should be in another `bib` file (maybe `Bibliography.bib` here, and you also need to add that to `\bibliography`). Keep `IEEEabrv.bib` clean (which can actually be found by bibtex as it is installed as part of LaTeX distribution)

Comment: the provided template starts with :
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
But eventhough they are in IEEE style they need to be abreviated

Comment: Yes, I am quite familiar with `IEEEtran` class and have written several journal papers. As I have said, to have an IEEE journal name abbreviated, you need to use the `@string` defined in `IEEEabrv.bib`, for example using `journal = IEEE_J_IT` for *IEEE Trans. Inf. Theory*.